# azure mobile service back-end SQL insert

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

my question is, on azure mobile service back-end when I run SQL insert on mssql.query like the one below

```
var sql = " INSERT INTO Customers 
(CustomerName, ContactName) VALUES (?, ?); ";

mssql.query(sql, [item.CustomerName, item.ContactName], {
        success: function(results) {
            request.execute();
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("error is: " + err);
        }   
    });
```

the data won't show up on azure portal website anymore. I know I can use the built in

```
todoItemTable.insert()
```

to insert, but sometimes the business logic is very complicated that it can only be done with in SQL. Is it the __version field that is causing the problem? If it is what should I put in when I insert?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs to see what might be going wrong. You do not need to worry about __version or other system columns when inserting a new record.

Is this in a table insert script? If so, you may not want request.execute() in your callback. That would insert the original record in addition to the record inserted in your mssql statement.

You may also have an issue because the mssql.query() can call its callback function multiple times depending on how many result messages the SQL produces. Have a variable like `requestExecuted` defined up with your `sql` variable, and in the mssql success callback, check it before executing the request.execute() call:

```
var requestExecuted = false;

mssql.query(sql, [item.CustomerName, item.ContactName], {
        success: function(results) {
            if (requestExecuted === false) {
              requestExecuted = true;
              request.execute();
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("error is: " + err);
        }   
    });
```

If this doesn't get you going, try adding console.log statements in the callback to see if it is getting called and how many times. Update your question if you have any more details from errors in your log.